# How do I join two tables using Table A in a one-to-many relationship with itself in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, left-join, one-to-many

I have two tables.

**The 'Store' table is a demographics table, with fields like these:**

> ID, ParentID, ConsolidationType

ID is the unique identifier for a given store.

ParentID may be either NULL or contain the ID of its parent store if it has a ConsolidationType of 'Secondary'.

ConsolidationType is either NULL, 'Primary', or 'Secondary'.

**The 'Sales' table has fields like these:**

> StoreID, SalesDate, SalesAmount

StoreID refers to an ID in the Store table.

---

I'm trying to get the total consolidated and individual sales for a given store in a single row of a single query. I've written a SQL query like the following:

```
SELECT 
Store.ID AS 'Store ID',
SUM(IF(YEAR(main.SalesDate) = 2012 AND QUARTER(main.SalesDate) = 1,main.SalesAmount,0)) AS 'Individual Sales',
SUM(IF(YEAR(main.SalesDate) = 2012 AND QUARTER(main.SalesDate) = 1 AND YEAR(secondaries.SalesDate) = 2012 AND QUARTER(secondaries.SalesDate) = 1,main.SalesAmount + secondaries.SalesAmount,0) AS 'Consolidated Sales'
FROM Store 
LEFT JOIN Sales AS 'main' ON Store.ID = main.StoreID 
LEFT JOIN Sales AS 'secondaries' ON Store.ParentID = secondaries.StoreID 
GROUP BY Store.ID
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work as intended. What am I missing? What's wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your query is generating a Cartesian-product (-like) result set.

Basically, a row from 'main' is getting repeated multiple times, for each matching row from 'secondaries'.

To get the result you want, join to the sales table just one time, and match on both the StoreID and the ParentID.

To get `Individual Sales`, only include in the SUM rows where the StoreID matches, something like this:

```
SELECT Store.ID AS `Store ID`
     , SUM(IF(main.StoreID = Store.ID,
       IF(YEAR(main.SalesDate) = 2012 AND QUARTER(main.SalesDate) = 1,main.SalesAmount,0)
       ,0)) AS `Individual Sales`
     , SUM(
       IF(YEAR(main.SalesDate) = 2012 AND QUARTER(main.SalesDate) = 1,main.SalesAmount,0)
       ) AS `Consolidated Sales`
  FROM Store 
  LEFT JOIN Sales AS `main` ON main.StoreID = Store.ID OR main.StoreID = Store.ParentID
 GROUP BY Store.ID
```

---

**UPDATE**

My bad. (DOH!) `ParentID` is on the `Store` table, not the `Sales` table.

The query above does not return the specified result.  (Working on it.)

I think you had the solution already...

Use the `ParentID` column in place of the `ID` column from the `Store` table.
Where the ParentID column is NULL, we use the value from the `ID` column.

```
SELECT IFNULL(Store.ParentID,Store.ID) AS `Store ID`
     , SUM(IF(main.StoreID = Store.ID,
       IF(YEAR(main.SalesDate) = 2012 AND QUARTER(main.SalesDate) = 1,main.SalesAmount,0)
       ,0)) AS `Individual Sales`
     , SUM(
       IF(YEAR(main.SalesDate) = 2012 AND QUARTER(main.SalesDate) = 1,main.SalesAmount,0)
       ) AS `Consolidated Sales`
  FROM Store s
  LEFT JOIN Sales AS `main` ON main.StoreID = Store.ID OR main.StoreID = Store.ParentID
 GROUP BY IFNULL(Store.ParentID,Store.ID)
```

---

This query returns the specified result set:

```
SELECT t.StoreID AS `Store ID`
     , SUM(IF(t.source='p',
       IF(YEAR(t.SalesDate) = 2012 AND QUARTER(t.SalesDate) = 1,t.SalesAmount,0)
       ,0)) AS `Individual Sales`
     , SUM(
       IF(YEAR(t.SalesDate) = 2012 AND QUARTER(t.SalesDate) = 1,t.SalesAmount,0)
       ) AS `Consolodiated Sales`
  FROM (    
         SELECT 'p' AS source
              , a.StoreID
              , a.SalesDate
              , a.SalesAmount
           FROM Sales a
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 's' AS source
              , s.ParentID
              , b.SalesDate
              , b.SalesAmount
           FROM Sales b
           JOIN Store s ON s.ID = b.StoreID
          WHERE s.ParentID IS NOT NULL
       ) t
 GROUP BY t.StoreID
 ORDER BY t.StoreID
```

This is not the most efficient, the inline view (or "derived table") is on the order of the size of the Sales table. It would be more efficient to push the predicates on the date down into the inline view, or to summarize by month, or quarter, in the derived table.

I would more likely return the "quarter" as part of the result set, to allow me to pull more than one quarter.

```
SELECT t.StoreID AS `Store ID`
     , t.SalesQuarter
     , SUM(IF(t.source='p',t.SalesAmount,0)) AS `Individual Sales`
     , SUM(t.SalesAmount) AS `Consolodiated Sales`
  FROM (    
         SELECT 'p' AS source
              , a.StoreID
              , ADDDATE(MAKEDATE(YEAR(a.SalesDate),1), INTERVAL FLOOR(MONTH(a.SalesDate)/4) QUARTER) AS SalesQuarter
              , SUM(a.SalesAmount) AS SalesAmount
           FROM Sales a
      --    WHERE a.SalesDate >= '2012-01-01'
      --      AND a.SalesDate < '2012-04-01'
          GROUP BY a.StoreID, SalesQuarter
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 's' AS source
              , s.ParentID
              , ADDDATE(MAKEDATE(YEAR(b.SalesDate),1), INTERVAL FLOOR(MONTH(b.SalesDate)/4) QUARTER) AS SalesQuarter
              , SUM(b.SalesAmount) AS SalesAmount
           FROM Sales b
           JOIN Store s ON s.ID = b.StoreID
          WHERE s.ParentID IS NOT NULL
      --      AND a.SalesDate >= '2012-01-01'
      --      AND a.SalesDate < '2012-04-01'
          GROUP BY s.ParentID, SalesQuarter
       ) t
 GROUP BY t.StoreID, t.SalesQuarter
 ORDER BY t.StoreID, t.SalesQuarter
```

Comment: This is MUCH closer, and thank you for that! The new problem here, though, is that it only finds the true consolidated total for the rows of the 'Secondary' stores; the 'Primary' store, having a NULL ParentID, has only its own sales in the Consolidated column.

To fix this, I'll just add the parent's ID to its own ParentID field, getting rid of the NULL value.

Comment: In the test that I ran against a single consolidated set, the Consolidated amount was correct for only one of the three stores returned. The secondary with no sales of its own returned the primary store's sales only in the Consolidated field, and the primary also only had its own sales in the Consolidated field.

Comment: @Uthr: Now, I understand the problem. The sales for the child stores aren't getting included. I will work on getting that fixed.  (ParentID is on the Store table, but not the Sales table...)

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to keep the filtering logic in the `WHERE` clause. Your original query might have too many `JOINS` and cases where there are no children might not give you what you expect. The `IS NULL` check in the `WHERE` below allows for stores with no children.

```
SELECT
  s.ID
  , SUM(s.SalesAmount) AS `Individual Sales`
  , SUM(s.SalesAmount) + SUM(c.SalesAmount) AS `Consolidated Sales`
FROM Store AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN Store AS c ON c.ParentID = s.ID
WHERE YEAR(s.SalesDate) = 2012 AND QUARTER(s.SalesDate) = 1
  AND (c.SalesDate IS NULL OR
    (YEAR(c.SalesDate) = 2012 AND QUARTER(c.SalesDate) = 1))
GROUP BY s.ID
```